# Trying to save Spark SQL Dataframes always leads in empty directories

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

Say I have a DataFrame called `df`. I run the following commands to attempt to save it locally:

```
df.coalesce(1).
   write.
   format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
   option("header", "true").
   parquet("example")
}
```

However, when I do this and go to check whether the file was created (in the directory `example`, I see a directory with only two files:

`_SUCCESS  ._SUCCESS.crc`

How can I get the DataFrame to save the file properly?

If it is important, I am also doing this through a Jupyter Notebook, so essentially, when I say locally, I mean I save it on the Jupyter Notebook server, NOT where Spark is running (I have Spark pointed to another master node).

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, Spark does all file operations through Hadoop, and it will make a copy of the directory on every node it is run, and the node running the command will only save the portion of data it has.

You can force a node to collect all of the data by using "coalesce(1)" or "repartition(1)" on the DataFrame, but you have no control over which node receives the single partition.

The result is, nodes (such as the driver) that do not have a partition of the dataset will only have a "_SUCCESS" file to show the operation was successful. You should find your data located on a different, and arbitrary, node.

I have not been able to solve this problem myself, but using a distributed filesystem, such as HDFS, would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing parquet with save (since I'm guessing you want the output in csv format and not parquet)

Try this:

```
df.coalesce(1).
   write.
   format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
   option("header", "true").
   save("example")
}
```

Comment: I did try that previously, and yeah sorry if the title was a bit misleading in that case. I was just also trying parquet for compactness. Unfortunately, I still get the empty directory.

Comment: See if removing header option helps.  I remember that sometimes the options for csv format don't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to run spark in local mode.  This will allow you to save locally but obviously is probably not what you want because you lose the main advantage of spark, running on a cluster.

The best, reasonable solution is to save to HDFS then copy the output to the local directory from there.